# How to implement Reducer when store initial state is an Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I'm trying to understand React- Redux basics, but I'm stuck in this particular case:

My code actions:

```
let todoId = 1

export const ADDTODO = 'AddTodo'
export const REMOVETODO = 'RemoveTodo'
export const TOINPROGRESS = 'ToInProgress'
export const TODONE = 'ToDone'

export function addTodo(payload){
return{
   type: ADDTODO,
   payload:{
      status: 'Todo',
      id: todoId++,
      title: payload.title,
      date:payload.date,
      description:payload.description,
      place:payload.place     
        }                                
    }       
}

export function removeTodo(todoId){
    return{
        type: REMOVETODO,
        payload:todoId
    }
}

export function toInProgress(todoId){
    return{
        type: TOINPROGRESS,
        payload:todoId
    }
}

export function toDone(todoId){
    return{
        type: TODONE,
        payload:todoId
    }
}
```

My attempt to reduce code:

```
import { addTodo, removeTodo, toInProgress, toDone } from '../actions';
const initialState = [];

const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {   
      case 'AddTodo':      
        return[
          ...state, {           
            date:action.payload.date,
            description:action.payload.description,
            id:action.payload.id,
            place:action.payload.place,
            status:action.payload.status,
            title:action.payload.title,
            
          }          
        ]  
       
 case 'RemoveTodo':
     console.log(state)            
     return {
         ...state,
         todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id  !== action.id)
     }

               
 case 'ToInProgress':             
     state.map(todo =>(todo.id===action.id)?{...todo,status:"InProgress"}:todo)     
         
 case 'ToDone':    
     state.map(todo =>(todo.id===action.id)?{...todo,status:"Done"}:todo)
                  
 default: 
     return state
  }
}
```

The only working method from todos reducer is AddTodo, can't figure out to RemoveTodo, ToInProgress & ToDo to work.
I'm getting a TypeError at RemoveTodo that says "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"
and undefined returns from the another two methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case state is an array, so **state.todos** will be undefined. You can fix 'RemoveTodo' case with something like

```
case 'RemoveTodo':          
    return state.filter(todo => todo.id  !== action.payload)
```

Comment: Wow! that was a fast answer Virtuoz! Tnx a lot for helping me. I've tryed your code, it doesn't removing the Object.

Comment: @MartinGonzalez I've changed the answer, can you check if it works now?

Comment: YESSS! I love you m8!!!! you have make my day! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You missed `return` in other cases and you don't need to assign each property out of `action.payload` just pass it as is, this is how it would look

```
const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "AddTodo":
        return [...state, action.payload];
      case "RemoveTodo":
        return state.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload.id);

      case "ToInProgress":
        return state.map((todo) =>
          todo.id === action.payload.id
            ? { ...todo, status: "InProgress" }
            : todo
        );

      case "ToDone":
        return state.map((todo) =>
          todo.id === action.payload.id ? { ...todo, status: "Done" } : todo
        );
      default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Tnx to you too sathya! the improvement for AddTodo works nicely! Sadly RemoveTodo throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined; And ToInProgress & ToDone doesn't update status.

Comment: I have updated the code, I didn't notice the other bugs at that time. you missed `action.payload.id` in your comparisons .